# Prove that a normal matrix is unitary/Hermitian

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm stuck with these two questions for while. I'd appreciate your help.

```
Given a normal matrix A, prove that:

a) It is unitary iff the magnitudes for all of its eigenvalues are 1.
b) It is Hermitian iff all of its eigenvalues are real.
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A normal matrix can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix.  The question is easy for diagonal matrices.